# Checkbox value to be checked by default in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
<input  type="checkbox" name="customPermissions[]" ng-model="form.customPermissions.examsList" value="examsList" ng-init="form.customPermissions.examsList=true"> {{phrase.examsList}}
```

I want to keep checkbox value as checked by default,tried as above but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: give ng-model to checkbox, and assign ng-model value in controller that you want to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-checked`true

```
<input ng-checked = "true"  type="checkbox" name="customPermissions[]" ng-model="form.customPermissions.examsList" value="examsList" ng-init="form.customPermissions.examsList=true"> {{phrase.examsList}}
```

Or you can assign ng-model value true initialy like this Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.checkVal = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
check : {{checkVal}}
<input  type="checkbox" name="customPermissions[]" ng-model="checkVal" value="examsList" ng-init="form.customPermissions.examsList=true"> sample
</div>
```

Comment: no prob. if this helped make sure to check as right answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<html ng-app ng-controller="testcontroller">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lookup" value="1">Default Checked</input>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lookup1" value="1">Default UnChecked</input>
 </html>`

 function testcontroller($scope){
  $scope.lookup = true;
   $scope.lookup1 = false;
 }`
```

Try this also get expected in the js fiddle link....

http://jsfiddle.net/kn373r5o/